# Windows 8 recovery failures

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8

I am asking a question here because I have finally come to the end of my tether on this issue. I have a HP pavilion PC running windows 8.1.

The hard drive had become damaged and no option on the recovery screen works as LITERALLY every option available is unable to perform. So i assume there is something corrupted in the recovery file.

First idea: is it possible to download this program from somewhere. if so where?

Failing this I had switched out the damaged hard drive (which is not straightforward in these PCs) and put in a decent one from another PC.However this PC was windows 7 so is better but not compatible with this PC.

So I now have the faulty one existing as an external HD. I had managed to back up everything on this. So i really dont care how I get it running again with windows as long as I don't have to buy another copy of 8.1.

Next option I have a copy of windows 8.1 OEM professional for a Dell PC. this is not compatible. I can't get hold of the windows OEM that came with this PC.

The situation now is that because I have tried every option in the recovery menu. Both hard drives are now both semi formatted so now are almost completely useless.

I have also managed to back up the recovery program/file from the original hard drive. And though I could perhaps write this to a restoration DVD?

So what I need to do is: 
Get windows 8.1 running using the activation Key from the BIOS.
On an old hard drive that probably needs a factory reset.

Any Ideas would be super.

Comment: [Order a recovery kit from HP](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/bph07143#AbT2)

Comment: Try to [download Windows 8.1 to a flash drive from Microsoft for free](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media) and see if it will activate using the OEM key in your UEFI. Failing that, I would go with Moab's suggestion.

Comment: amazing. i just needed the link. thankyou so much. nobody at microsoft or hp gave me this.